# Search box for website

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, ajax

I have tried this code and this is working only for one page when i am in basintap page but i want to know how to search anything when i am in another page?

```
<?php
$query = $_GET['query']; 
$min_length = 2;
if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 
$sql ="Select * from basintap where keywords like '%keywords%'";
$run_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query) > 0){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){
$id    = $row['id'];
$cat   = $row['cat'];
$brand = $row['brand'];
$name = $row['name'];
$image = $row['image'];
echo "<div class='col-md-4'>
<div class='panel panel-info'>
<div class='panel-heading'>$name</div>
<div class='panel-body'>
<img src='basintap/$image' style='width:160px; height:250px;'/>
</div>
</div>
</div>  ";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a separate table per page, then you are going to have to restructure your database in order to solve your problem using a home grown solution. Keep all pages in one table, distinguished by a separate field and/or index.

Alternatively if it's too much hassle, just plug [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) into your site.

Comment: we have a single database but have different tables .We need a algorithm for searching products from those tables.

Comment: Do you have a separate table per "page"? Or are the number of tables fixed?

Comment: I have separate table per page.

Comment: Then that is bad database design. Do as I said in the answer, restructure your database such that every page is within a single table, separated by a key per page, and then perform a search over that single table only.

Comment: Or use a third party search service, like Algolia, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: But every table has different structure some table include design,material...etc but some table doesn't include this things.

Comment: For that i have to paid but i don't have enough money to use Algolia.

Comment: But, from the looks of it, every table must have a `keywords` column? ;-) Put all the common page fields into one table, then create some separate tables with the unique fields linking back to the common table using forein keys. Modelling your database using an ER diagram or such can help you with your design.

Comment: As per the pricing page, it is free for indexing 10,000 items (so to speak).

Comment: Thank you so much sir ..i will try for this.Then i will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change your "basintap" string from your query with the table name you'd like to search into.

```
$sql ="Select * from [place-table-name-here] where keywords like '%keywords%'";
```

Comment: I have lots of tables in my website if i do like this then it will take lots of time to search a query.Is there any easy algorithm for searching query which take less time.

Comment: we have a single database but have different tables .We need a algorithm for searching products from those tables.